# Function nested inside React component not using Vitest mock passed as prop

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

I'm trying to mock a handler passed as a prop to a component that calls it as part of a callback to a form submission. I'm using `vitest` an `react-testing-library`. Here is the component:

```
const APIKeyInput = ({ handleSubmit }: APIKeyInputProps) => {
  const onSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleSubmit(event.currentTarget.elements.apiKey.value);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="apiKey">Insira sua chave para a API:</label>
      <input type="text" name="apiKey" />
      <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

In the test, I create a mock with `vi.fn()` and pass it as the `handleSubmit` prop. Here is the test module:

```
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from "vitest";
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import APIKeyInput from "./App";

describe("APIKeyInput", () => {
  it("calls onSubmit when submitted", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const onSubmitMock = vi.fn();
    render(<APIKeyInput handleSubmit={onSubmitMock} />);

    expect(onSubmitMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    const apiSubmit = screen.getByRole("button");

    await user.click(apiSubmit);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(onSubmitMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Using logging, I can see that `onSubmit` gets called when the `user.click(apiSubmit)` is triggered but, for some reason, `onSubmitMock` does not. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I was importing `APIKeyInput` without curly brackets, but wasn't exporting it as `default`. Silly mistake. I would hope that some of the packages involved would have given me a helpful error message for something like that.